# javascript object problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to mocking mongodb map-reduce.

```
function some_function(){
    ....
    call_some (some_object);
    ....
}

function call_some (some_object){
    // In here,
    // How could I use this keyword instead of some_object?
    // some_object.something => this.something
}
```

in javascript or jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `call_some` using [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)'s [`call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
function some_function() {
    // ...
    call_some.call(some_object);
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to call it in a special way, try this:

```
function call_some(some_object) {
    if(this !== some_object) {
        return call_some.apply(some_object, arguments);
    }
    // do something interesting here
    // this === some_object
}
```